# Custom tab bar icon not "filled in" when selected

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a custom tab bar icon and made sure to set the background to transparent.  The outline of the icon highlights when selected, but doesn't fill as system icons do.

From the Human Interface Guidelines manual:

> Provide two versions of custom tab bar icons. Provide icons for both
>   the selected and unselected states. The selected icon is often a
>   filled-in version of the unselected icon, but some designs call for
>   variations to this approach.

My question is after I created the two versions of the icon as directed, how do you set it?

Comment: are you using Storyboard?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using the Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using storyboard you need to select your tabViewController and define the tab item properties according your needs

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Very much.  I can't believe I missed that!